# RSS Feed on another site PHP

Tags: php, rss, wordpress

i have a problem here...im trying to show the feed of a blog(wordpress) in my website...and that is the return what i have...i already have the image, title and link of the post...but the description is coming like an xml object...i tried to read that but i had not success...someone can help me??

```
  object(SimpleXMLElement)[74]
    public 'title' =  string '10 curiosidades sobre a Pizza' (length=29)
    public 'link' =  string 'www.site.com.br/blog/index.php/10-curiosidades-sobre-a-pizza/' (length=71)
    public 'comments' =  string 'www.site.com.br/blog/index.php/10-curiosidades-sobre-a-pizza/#comments' (length=80)
    public 'pubDate' =  string 'Wed, 14 Aug 2013 13:08:49 +0000' (length=31)
    public 'category' =>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)[76]
    public 'guid' =  string 'www.site.com.br/blog/?p=1254' (length=38)
    public 'description' =  
      object(SimpleXMLElement)[75]
    public 'enclosure' =  
      object(SimpleXMLElement)[77]
        public '@attributes' =  
          array (size=3)
          'url' =  string 'www.site.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/pizza-RC-Fones-150x150.jpg' (length=84)
          'length' =  string '9873' (length=4)
          'type' =  string 'image/jpg' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the methods of the [SimpleXMLElement class](https://www.php.net//manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to extract the information you need. So, for example, to get the title, use `$title = $object->title;`.

Some of those items are themselves SimpleXMLElement objects. To get information out of them, simply do the same thing:

```
// assuming the description has a title...

$description = $object->description->title;
```

Comment: when i try to get the attributes of description returns another object and i dont know why...when i try to get the attributes of 'enclosure' it's fine...

Comment: RSS feeds are published as XML documents. XML is a hierarchical data structure - an element can have "child" elements, which can have more child elements, etc. etc. Each of those elements can be represented by an instance of `SimpleXMLElement`. To get at the data "inside" those elements, use the methods and properties of the `SimpleXMLElement` class (a link to the docs is in the answer). You'll probably have to do some experimenting to get the values you want.